# Saving output (context) embeddings in word2vec (gensim implementation) as a final model

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I have studied `word2vec` implementation in gensim, I am aware that input vectors are in `syn0`, output vectors are in `syn1` and `syn1neg` if negative sampling.

I know I can access similarity between input and output embeddings like this:

```
outv = KeyedVectors()
outv.vocab = model.wv.vocab
outv.index2word = model.wv.index2word  
outv.syn0 = model.syn1neg 
inout_similars = outv.most_similar(positive=[model['cousin']])
```

My question is, if it is possible to save output embeddings (from `syn1` or `syn1neg` matrix) as final model. For example, when `model.save()`, so that it outputs output embeddings (or where exactly in the code of `word2vec.py` I could access and modify that). I need this in order to use these output embeddings as input to classifier. I have done it previously in brute-force approach, so I would like to access output embeddings easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object `outv`, as an instance of `KeyedVectors`, has its own `save()` method (inherited from the `SaveLoad` superclass defined in `gensim/utils.py`) and `save_word2vec_format()` method. Each would save them in a manner you could reload into Python code again later.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @gojomo
Actually, I have just realized it myself. True, I could simply call `save()` or `save_word2vec_format()` on `outv` object.
Previously, without KeyedVectors class, it was a cumbersome job to retrieve output matrix. New api tackles many other similar issues. Thanks a lot!